# XML must be well-formed issued for web.xml file of a JSP/Servlet project

Tags: xml, jsp, servlets, web.xml

Getting the error below from Eclipse. What does it mean *"must be well-formed"*? Is there a mistake in the xml?

> The markup in the document following the root element must be
>   well-formed

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<display-name>...</display-name>
<servlet>     
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>  
      <servlet-class>...</servlet-class> 
        <init-param>        
        <param-name>config</param-name> 
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>   
        </init-param>     
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>  
          <servlet-name>action</servlet-name> 
          <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please post your whole web.xml.  If this *is* your whole web.xml, it's definitely not well-formed, as it's missing the root element.

Comment: @DonRoby

I've updated the XML with a few missing lines, but that's all there's to it.

Comment: Well, now it's missing the start tag for the root element.  Which makes it definitely not well-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what a well-formedness error occurs when your tags are not properly nested/not properly closed. It appears to be the most likely case for you since you already have content in your xml. The characters < > & need to be escaped in XML text.

Upload your file to - http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/xml-check.html
to see the well-formedness errors.

Change your XML to:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app>
        <display-name>...</display-name>
        <servlet>     
            <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>  
              <servlet-class>...</servlet-class> 
                <init-param>        
                <param-name>config</param-name> 
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>   
                </init-param>     
               <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
         </servlet>
         <servlet-mapping>  
                  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name> 
                  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>
        </web-app>
```