# JSP markup error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

Am trying to create a simple JSP page, but i get this error when ever i try to run the web application(in eclipse):

`"The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed."`

This is my JSP code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Entry Form</h1>

    <form name="Name Input Form" action="response.jsp">
        Enter your name:
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: What does your web.xml look like?

Comment: It's the auto-generated web.xml am using.I didn't change anything.

Comment: I can't see your 'auto-generated' web.xml unless you post it. Also, is that the entire error you get or is there more to it?

Comment: I didn't post it because i don't think it has anything to do with the problem am having.I think this is just a markup problem.if you think otherwise could you tell me why?

Comment: Here is at least one example of why you would like to have your web.xml checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433534/xml-must-be-well-formed-issued-for-web-xml-file-of-a-jsp-servlet-project

Comment: Is that the server complaining or the client? About *this* page?

Comment: The client.I haven't uploaded it to GAE yet.

Answer (score 0):

`meta` does not have a closing tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Oh, i solved that one already. Forgot to change it before posting it here.Although that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `meta` element in `head` tag should not have a corresponding closing `meta` element. Try changing `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </meta>` to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`.

I think you should remove whitespace from the value of the `name` attribute of the form. It might not be the source of your issues but rather a convention.